# $\phi(x)-\psi(x)=(\phi(x_0)-\psi(x_0))e^{-\int_{x_0}^x a(t) dt}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, continuity

I am looking at the following exercise:

If $\phi, \psi$ solutions of the differential equation $y'+a(x)y=b(x)$ on an interval $I$, where $a,b$ continuous on $I$ and $x_0 \in I$, show that:

$$\phi(x)-\psi(x)=(\phi(x_0)-\psi(x_0))e^{-\int_{x_0}^x a(t) dt}$$

There is the following remark:

If $I$ is a closed and bounded interval, for example $I=[c,d]$ then the above exercise tells us that: if $\phi, \psi$ are "near" at $x_0$ then they are "near" at each $x \in I$

i.e. if $|\phi(x_0)-\psi(x_0)|< \epsilon$ for some $\epsilon>0$, then because of the fact that $a$ is continuous on $I$ we have that $\max_{x \in I} e^{-\int_{x_0}^x a(t)dt}$ exists and is a finite number, let $M:=\max_{x \in I} e^{-\int_{x_0}^x a(t)dt}$.

Therefore, $|\phi(x)-\psi(x)|< \epsilon \cdot M , \forall x \in I$.

Could you explain me how from the fact that $a$ is continuous on $I$ we deduce that $\max_{x \in I} e^{-\int_{x_0}^x a(t)dt}$ exists and is a finite number?

Also, which would be the difference if we wouldn't have a closed and bounded interval?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $a$ is continuous, then its anti-derivative is continuous, then the composition with the continuous exponential again yields a continuous function. Thus there is a maximum for this positive function above every compact interval.

Comment: Nice :) So does this mean that each continuous function has a maximum?
$$$$
Also would the remark also hold if we did'nt have a closed and bounded interval?

Comment: No, of course not, see the exponential function. The restriction to a compact set is essential (Weierstrass). In finite dimension this is equivalent to closed and bounded (Heine-Borel).

Answer (score 2):

if $a(x)$ is continuous on a closed interval, then $m \le a(x) \le M$ for all $x$ in that interval. now $m(x-x_0) \le \int_{x_0}^x a(t)dt \le M(x-x_0)$ as long as $x_0 \le x.$ that gives you $e^{-M(x-x_0)} \le e^{-\int_{x_0}^x a(t) dt} \le e^{-m(x-x_0)}$

make $|x-x_0|$ small enough to get the desired result.

Comment: So if $m>0$ then $\max {e^{-m(x-x_0)}}=1$, otherwise we cannot calculate it in the general case, right?
$$$$
Also the remark doesn't hold if the interval isn't closd and bounded because in this case the maximum isn't a finite number, right?

Comment: if $a$ has a vertical asymptote and $\lim_{x \to b} = -\infty$ somewhere at $x = b,$ then $\int_{x_0}^x  a(t)\, dt$  will be unbounded.

Comment: Could you explain it further to me? :/

Comment: take an $I$ that is not closed. for example, $I=[0,1), x_0 = 0, a(x) = -\dfrac1{(x-1)^2}.$ computing $\int_0^x a(t) \, dt = -\dfrac{1}{1-t}|_0^x =1 -\dfrac{1}{1-x} \to -\infty$ as $x \to 1.$ the compactness of $I$ is essential for continuous function $a$ to have a global max and min on $I.$